# Cannot set property 'xxxx' of undefined angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to make a simple application with ionic (angular)
my problem is :  `Cannot set property 'origin' of undefined`

this is the interface Product.ts

```js
export interface Products{
      id: number;
      new: boolean;
      origin: string;
      branch: string;
      product: string;
      quantity: string;
      productId: string;
      Detail_product: string;
      Installed: boolean;

}
```

and here the ts code :

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.makeObject("03-2-450-2");
}

 makeObject(qrcode) {
    let obj: Products ;
    let Qrstring: string = qrcode;
    obj.origin! = Qrstring.substring(0, Qrstring.indexOf("-"));
    console.log(obj.origin);

  }
}
```

Comment: You've defined the type but didn't initialize it. Try `let obj: Products = Object.create(null);`.

Comment: thanks, friend for the help it is work :D but can you give me a link to know more about `Object.create(null)` to know how to use it next time

Comment: You could see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#custom_and_null_objects). It discusses b/n the statements `Object.create(null)` vs `Object.create({})`.

Comment: thank you one more time friend that mean a lot to me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj` is never assigned to anything. It is only given a type. You have to use e.g. `let obj: Products = {};`.
Then you will have the problem, that all the properties of `obj` are undefined.

It would be better to assing it as you go. Example:

```
let Qrstring: string = qrcode;
let obj: Products = {
    origin: Qrstring.substring(0, Qrstring.indexOf("-")),
// set the other required properties
};
obj.origin! = Qrstring.substring(0, Qrstring.indexOf("-"));
```

Note: if you don't need all properties you can mark them as optinal in the template with the questionmark operator. Example `Installed: boolean;` see: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-tmupfv

You can then cast it with `let obj: Products = {} as unknown as Products;` (very hacky, may lead to problems later on)

Comment: thank you I try your solution and it works perfectly :D that means a lot to me

Comment: then just mark it as accapted, so others will see that it is soved for you